# Dask groupby apply behaving wierdly

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am trying to run groupby apply in dask for this test example

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
               'b': [4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]},
              index=[0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(tdf, npartitions=3)

def func(df):
    df['b'] = df.b - df.b.mean()
    return df

meta = tdf.groupby('a').apply(func)
rddf = ddf.groupby('a').apply(func,meta=tmeta).compute()
```

i am executing this code in jupyter notebook anaconda python_version = 3.6 on windows, i got error **'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'**
and repeatedly executing only the rddf part of code,i got

```
a   b
6   5   0.0
9   9   0.0
0   1   0.0
1   2   0.0
8   6   0.0
9   7   0.0
9   8   0.0
3   3   0.0
5   4   0.0
```

why is it happening,for the same code,different results?

Comment: Is not possible create default non duplicate index by `tdf = tdf.reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: i tried adding 
    `tdf = tdf.reset_index(drop=True)`
 but when i execute rddf i am getting two outputs

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get the expected result by using df.copy(),but still dont know what was causing the problem

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
               'b': [4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]},
              index=[0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(tdf, npartitions=3)
def func(df):
   df = df.copy()
   df['b'] = df.b - df.b.mean()
   return df
meta = tdf.groupby('a').apply(func)
rddf = ddf.groupby('a').apply(func,meta=meta).compute()
```

meta is

```
        a   b
a           
1   0   1   0.0
2   1   2   0.0
3   3   3   0.0
4   5   4   0.0
5   6   5   0.0
6   8   6   0.0
7   9   7   0.0
8   9   8   0.0
9   9   9   0.0
```

rddf is

```
       a    b
a           
5   6   5   0.0
9   9   9   0.0
1   0   1   0.0
2   1   2   0.0
6   8   6   0.0
7   9   7   0.0
8   9   8   0.0
3   3   3   0.0
4   5   4   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `drop=True` for unique index:

```
tdf = tdf.reset_index(drop=True)
```

then get all `0` values, because `groupby` by `a` with length 1 - so `b` values are same as `mean`s.

If change values of `a`:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
tdf = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], # double 1
               'b': [4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]},
              index=[0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9])

tdf = tdf.reset_index(drop=True)

ddf = dd.from_pandas(tdf, npartitions=3)
```

---

```
def func(df):
    df['b'] = df.b - df.b.mean()
    return df

meta = tdf.groupby('a').apply(func)
rddf = ddf.groupby('a').apply(func).compute()
print (meta)
   a    b
0  1 -0.5
1  1  0.5
2  3  0.0
3  4  0.0
4  5  0.0
5  6  0.0
6  7  0.0
7  8  0.0
8  9  0.0

print (rddf)
   a    b
4  5  0.0
8  9  0.0
5  6  0.0
6  7  0.0
7  8  0.0
0  1 -0.5
1  1  0.5
3  4  0.0
2  3  0.0
```

For same output sort index:

```
print (rddf.sort_index())
   a    b
0  1 -0.5
1  1  0.5
2  3  0.0
3  4  0.0
4  5  0.0
5  6  0.0
6  7  0.0
7  8  0.0
8  9  0.0
```

Comment: i tried the same, but it is breaking at
`ddf.groupby('a').apply(func).compute()`
at `get_async(pool.apply_async, len(pool._pool), dsk, result,` sometimes i get the above result but after again running group

by it throws Value error,i will try executing outside notebook may be it it is with async

Comment: Hmmm, do you use last version of pandas and dask? for me your sample working nice.

Comment: pandas - '0.20.2' and dask - '0.14.3'

Comment: i was getting the error on the above test example code,if it behaves as expected i was about to use it to real data

Comment: Hmmm, I use `0.20.3` and `0.15.2` dask under `python 3.5.1` and windows. And for me it working.

Comment: can u try executing multiple times only the groupby on rddf? checking if it throws any Value error

Comment: I run it 6 times and no problem :(

Comment: Hmm, probably will check the same doing in a virtual env using versions of yours,then can narrow down

Comment: It is worst scenario if working for me and for you not :( But I have no idea. Only one thing - I remove `meta` from `ddf.groupby('a').apply(func).compute()` because no varaible `tmeta`. But it seems there is no problem, but check it.

Comment: i tried using synchronous scheduler,`ddf.groupby('a').apply(func,meta=meta).compute(get=dask.get)`,i am getting expected result,probably it is a problem with async, i saw in async of dask, there was some code below the executed function to clean up dead pools,which is not getting called.may be it is the issue

Comment: I use `dask` not very often, so I have no idea.